# How to restrict posts only from a certain category

Tags: user-access

I'm making use of this custom code to my loop.php file to restrict non-registered members access to posts from a certain category (cat 1)

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() && $cat == '1') { ?> 
<?php the_content(); ?> 
<?php } else { ?> 
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

However this piece of code doesn't help much as it restricts all posts from other categories as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php 
    //first check if its the category in question
    if ($cat == '1') { 
        //then if the user is logged in show the content
        if (is_user_logged_in()){
            the_content();
        }else{ //if not show the excerpt
            the_excerpt();
        }
    }else{ // and if its not the category show the content
        the_content();
    }
?>
```

### Update

Judging by your comments you are some defining `$cat` before the check so add:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
```

before the conditional code.

Comment: BRILLIANT!! Thanks a ton, I was trying to use elseifs and so on. Thanks!!

Comment: glad y could help.

Comment: Opps, sorry. Was kinda quick to jump the gun. With the above code even posts in cat 1 are being displayed openly.

Comment: Looking at this code, I think in the last instance of else, probably an if statement should come in as well? if its not the category and ignore user status, then show content ??

Comment: with this code you only check the user status if the post category is `1` assuming that you set `$cat` correctly.

Comment: are you sure that $cat holds the category id of the post?

Comment: Yep, `mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post`

I tried adding -158,-161 to the $cat as well but still no go.

Comment: `$cat` in not automatically defined if its set in the url you need to define it yourself, i updated my answer.